# How to set background-image with image-set in css3?

Tags: css

I want to set a background image for the body using [`image-set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-set()) by using this snippet :

```
body {
  background-image: image-set(
    "./images/dog-puppy-on-garden-royalty-free-image-1586966191.jpg"
  );
}
```

But the `body` stills white.

However, when I use `url()` the `body` changed its background.

```
body {
  background-image: url("./images/dog-puppy-on-garden-royalty-free-image-1586966191.jpg");
}
```

Comment: I think you will need the prefix: https://caniuse.com/css-image-set the support is still low

Comment: @TemaniAfif I used the prefix `-webkit` but nothing happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `url` and consider the prefix. Don't forget the the resolution like stated in the MDN doc:

> Every image within an image-set() must have a unique resolution.

```css
body {
  background-image: -webkit-image-set(url("https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300") 1x);
}
```

Comment: But why they did not put `url()` in the documentation: [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-set()#using_image-set_to_provide_alternative_background-image_options)

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine-Aladdin both should work but I think the non-url version is still something new and not yet supported (like image-set()). Need to dig into the Spec to better understand: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-4/#image-set-notation

Answer (score 0):

You still need to add the URL

```
body {
  background-image: image-set(
   url("./images/dog-puppy-on-garden-royalty-free-image-1586966191.jpg")
  );
```

}